# How to get steps count on hourly basis from HealthKit Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I need to plot graph for steps taken by user on hourly basis on any specific date. But if the user's steps start today at 3:58 pm and end today at 4:10 pm then I am getting just one HKStatistics object for this period of time. I am not able to break this data into two samples as I need to get steps taken in the 3-4 pm slot and the 4-5 pm slot.

```
  static func getSteps(date: Date, duration: DateComponents, completion: @escaping ([HKSample]) -> Void) {
        let quantityType : Set = [HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!]

        let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
        let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)
        if let endOfDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: duration, to: startOfDay) {
            var interval = DateComponents()
            interval.hour = 1
            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: endOfDay, options: .strictStartDate)

            let query = HKSampleQuery.init(sampleType:stepsQuantityType,
                                                 predicate: predicate,
                                                 limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
                                                 sortDescriptors: nil,
                                                 resultsHandler: { (query, results, error) in
                                                    guard let result = results else {

                                                                            return
                                                                        }
                                                   // print("result healthkit",result.description)
                                                    //print("Total count:",)
                                                    completion(result)
            })

            healthStore.execute(query)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `HKSampleQuery` for charting quantity types. `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` is designed for this purpose and will split samples that fall into separate regions of your chart for you. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery?language=objc) for examples of how to build the query and use its results.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, you can't split the sample. That's the all the information that's available. Steps are not stored step-by-step; they're aggregated into blocks to reduce power and storage requirements (mostly power; it's easier to accumulate a value in hardware and periodically read it than to query the real time clock every single time a step is detected).

In order to do what you're discussing, you'll need to average the steps over the period. So if there were 100 steps over the period 3:58p to 4:07p, that averages 10 steps/minute, and you would allocate 20 steps to the 3p-4p block and 80 steps to the 4p-5p block. That's the best information you have.